# how to restart a for loop if condition is met

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, restart

I have a dataframe of percentages and am trying to adjust it so that all percents in each column are at least 2 percentage points different from all other percents in that column so that they will be displayed nicely on a chart.

```
df <- data.frame(c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),c(29, 26, 25, 12),c(8, 7, 3, 2))
names(df) <- c("group","var1","var2")
```

Currently I'm using a for-loop, which works except that it is one-directional:

```
for(c in 2:ncol(df){
 for(r in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[r,c]-order_df[r+1,c]<2){
    group <- df$group[r]
    df[[c]][df$group==group] <- df[[c]][df$group==group]+2
  }
 }
}
```

In this situation, when r=1 and c=2, the if condition wouldn't be met, because 29-26>2, then r=2 and c=2, the if condition would be met and 26 would become 28. However, that puts it too close to 29, so I want to go back to r=1 and recheck, so that 29 can be moved up to 31. Is there a way to restart a for-loop in r if a specific condition is met?

Expected output:

```r
expected <- data.frame(group=c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),var1=c(31, 28, 25, 12),var2=c(10, 7, 5, 2))
```

Comment: I don't think a double-`for` loop is necessarily the best way to go about this, but either way ... what is the (or "one") expected output given this input?

Comment: Note that you can avoid overlaying points (without messing with the original data) with base R's `jitter` function and `ggplot`'s `jitter` argument to `geom_point`.

Comment: As I_O said, this is the wrong approach for this problem.  But in the general case, you should avoid setting up a conditional whose output will change a previous conditional.  There's the very real risk of an infinite loop.

Comment: In addition to I_O's `jitter`/`geom_point` recommendation, if your only concern is during plotting and you are already using `ggplot2`, consider `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` as well, it tries very hard to keep labels from overlapping.

Comment: @I_O My issue with using these functions is that they seem to be random. Some of my datapoints don't need to be jittered, while others are completely overlapping (the actual data contains one column that is 1, 2, 2, 2). Using either of the `jitter` functions doesn't give me enough variation in some columns or too much in others. Additionally, I need the jittered values to be proportional to my original values (i.e., if I have c(3,6,7,8), I can't have the jittered values be c(4.5, 2.1, 7.2, 9.1)), which seems to happen with the base R `jitter` function

Comment: @r2evans the intended output would be `df <- data.frame(c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),c(31, 28, 25, 12),c(10, 7, 5, 2))`

Comment: I think it's worth continuing the discussion of "why" you want to do this. Is it just for plots? Is it because you're setting for a simulation or survey and you need starting conditions to be clearly different? Are `var1` and `var2` independent, or are you considering distances between them? There's no safety in the initial heuristic preventing a value to be `(nrow(df) - 1) * 2` values different from when it started (since you always add 2), and I don't know that it's much better alternating or doing something else fancy to do both pluses and minuses.

Comment: How does `order_df` look like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but assuming you are needing to more than "just" plot things ...

```r
for (col in 2:3) {
  for (i in rev(seq_len(nrow(df)-1))) {
    df[[col]][i] <- df[[col]][i] + 2*sum(abs(df[[col]][i] - df[[col]][-(1:i)]) < 2)
  }
}
```

Another way that uses R's `lapply` fairly fluidly is:

```r
df
#    group var1 var2
# 1 group1   29    8
# 2 group2   26    7
# 3 group3   25    3
# 4 group4   12    2
df[,2:3] <- lapply(df[,2:3], function(z) {
  for (i in rev(seq_along(z))[-1]) {
    z[i] <- z[i] + 2*sum(abs(z[i] - z[-(1:i)]) < 2)
  }
  z
})
df
#    group var1 var2
# 1 group1   31   10
# 2 group2   28    7
# 3 group3   25    5
# 4 group4   12    2
```

---

Data

```r
df <- data.frame(group=c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),var1=c(29, 26, 25, 12),var2=c(8, 7, 3, 2))
expected <- data.frame(group=c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),var1=c(31, 28, 25, 12),var2=c(10, 7, 5, 2))
```